# How do I get the username for the IAM user when trying to connect to Google CloudSQL using a unix socket on a cloudrun instance?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have the following code to get my username from a env var in a run instance using Java...

```
    String dbUser = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("DB_USER")).orElseGet(() -> {
        EXIT.accept("You must Provide a DB Username");
        return null;
    });
```

My main question is, since I am using IAM auth, is there a way I can get this username without having to use an Env Variable. Kind of like how the password can be empty.

Comment: Have you tried to follow step here in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default_1)?

Comment: Yes thank you I have it working this way but the question is about how do I get the username being used without using an env var. It has to be in the context of the run instance somewhere and shouldn't need managed. So I am looking for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication#automatic), the username must be provided, not the password. The user access token act as validation of the user name account and grant the authorized users.

Comment: This wasn't the question the question is how can I query for the username instead of having to use an env var.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. You can't. You must provide at least the username, not the password

Comment: Right so isn't there a way to get that from context since it knows what context it is running under and therefore what user?

Comment: Basically I don't want to have to change the env var every-time I change what user the run instance is running under when that info should be available from the instance itself

Comment: You can use the email of the current user if you know it. You can also use this API: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/users/list

Comment: Right but the IAM user in theory will change per environment and this requires another secret